# Debug build doesn't detect code changes

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, timestamp

I'm currently a beginner at programming with C++. Taking a course I found online. Right now, I'm just writing a program which the course keeps on building upon in every video. It's good stuff.

Just today, I've been working to the program a bit more. And for some odd reason, without me having adjusted anything, the Debug is not detecting code changes.

I've tried everything from undoing my steps to the point where it would actually take changes, and have gone as far as to make mistakes on purpose so that it would give me a compiler error, but no. It just runs the same program which is has been running ever since this incident has started.

I've searched a bit and I think it has something to do with the debug timestamps? I'm not sure. I've tried to look for these timestamps in Visual C++ and the files but found nothing.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the solution after making the changes?

Comment: `Build -> Clean <Project name>`

Comment: Or more scorched-earth. `Build -> Clean Solution`

Comment: As others have said, Build -> Nuke it from Orbit.